# Laravel: Polymorphic types table vs many types tables

Tags: laravel, database-design, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5.4

I am trying to determine what the best way to many a relationship describing a type would be using Laravel.  For example, I might have a user model that can be of many types.  Everything I have ever been taught would suggest I need to make a users_types.  However, if I wanted to use Eloquent to reference this relationship, I would also need to make a UserType model and an IdentificationType model.  For example:

```
// User Class
public function type() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\UserType');
}

// User Type Class
public function users(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

$user->type->description;  // Could return 'casual'
```

This seems like it could quickly become ridiculous if I have a bunch of models and each one could potentially have a "type" or maybe a "status".

Would it be better to make a single types table or a single status table and manage everything with a polymorphic relationship, or is that bad database design? Is there a better way to accomplish this using Query Builder instead of Eloquent?

Comment: What other things could be of a same type as a user?

Comment: @apokryfos Lets say I have 100 other models and maybe 50 of them have types.  Now I need 50 more types tables and 50 more types models. That seems ridiculous when I could just have 1 polymorphic types table and 1 type model. However, I don't know if that is "good practice"

Comment: Let's say you have an e-commerce page and say you have a `Product` entity which may also have a `Type`. Is there any chance that a `User` may share a type with a `Product` and if not does it make any semantic sense to put all types together in the same table?

Comment: @apokryfos Absolutely!  I could have a Product with a type of "primary" and a User with a type of "primary"

Answer (score 0):

If it makes semantic sense then using a polymorphic relationship is reasonable. The example Laravel sets is with commentable entities. A commentable entity can either be a video or a post (both allow comments).

In your case you'd need to do something like these tables:

```
typable_type
type_id | typable_id | typable_type

type
id | name
```

and use:

```
public function type() {
      return $this->morphToMany(Type::class,"type");
}
```

There's no practical reason why you can't do this anyway, in your case. There is however a semantic reason. Example:

A `User` can be of type `primary` , a `Product` can be of type `primary` however does that mean the same thing? For example does it make sense to say : "Everything primary can be accessed through this page" in short when you say primary user and primary product, does the word primary carry the same meaning?  If the answer is yes then polymorphism is something you should use.